# Specializing Imported Function in GHC Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm working on a project right now where I'm dealing with
the [`Prim`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.2.0/docs/Data-Primitive-Types.html) typeclass and I need to ensure that a particular
function I've written is specialized. That is, I need to make sure that
when I call it, I get a specialized version of the function in which the
`Prim` dictionaries get inlined into the specialized
definition instead of being passed at runtime.

Fortunately, this is a pretty well-understood thing in GHC. You can just
write:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE foo :: ByteArray Int -> Int #-}
foo :: Prim a => ByteArray a -> Int
foo = ...
```

And in my code, this approach is working fine. But, since typeclasses are
open, there can be `Prim` instances that I don't know about yet when
the library is being written. This brings me to the problem at hand.
The GHC user guide's [documentation of `SPECIALIZE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-pragma)
provides two ways to use it. The first is putting `SPECIALIZE` at the
site of the definition, as I did in the example above. The second is
putting the `SPECIALIZE` pragma in another module where the [function is imported](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-for-imported-functions).
For reference, the example the user manual provides is:

```
module Map( lookup, blah blah ) where
  lookup :: Ord key => [(key,a)] -> key -> Maybe a
  lookup = ...
  {-# INLINABLE lookup #-}

module Client where
  import Map( lookup )

  data T = T1 | T2 deriving( Eq, Ord )
  {-# SPECIALISE lookup :: [(T,a)] -> T -> Maybe a
```

The problem I'm having is that this is not working in my code. The project
is [on github](https://github.com/andrewthad/btree/tree/109eca9bd234718f286f25f247b20ac34eefb84f),
and the relevant lines are:

- [`bench/Main.hs` line 24](https://github.com/andrewthad/btree/blob/109eca9bd234718f286f25f247b20ac34eefb84f/bench/Main.hs#L24)
- [`src/BTree/Compact.hs` line 149](https://github.com/andrewthad/btree/blob/109eca9bd234718f286f25f247b20ac34eefb84f/src/BTree/Compact.hs#L149)

To run the benchmark, run these commands:

```
git submodule init && git submodule update
cabal new-build bench && ./dist-newstyle/build/btree-0.1.0.0/build/bench/bench
```

When I run the benchmark as is, there is a part of the output that reads:

```
Off-heap tree, Amount of time taken to build:
0.293197796
```

If I uncomment [line 151 of BTree.Compact](https://github.com/andrewthad/btree/blob/109eca9bd234718f286f25f247b20ac34eefb84f/src/BTree/Compact.hs#L151),
that part of the benchmark runs fifty times faster:

```
Off-heap tree, Amount of time taken to build:
5.626834e-2
```

It's worth pointing out that the function in question, `modifyWithM`, is enormous.
It's implementation is over 100 lines, but I do not think this should make a
difference. The docs claim:

> ... mark the definition of f as INLINABLE, so that GHC guarantees to expose an unfolding regardless of how big it is.

So, my understanding is that, if specializing at the definition site works, it
should always be possible to instead specialize at the call site. I would appreciate
any insights from people who understand this machinery better than I do, and I'm
happy to provide more information if something is unclear. Thanks.

EDIT: I've realized that in the git commit I linked to in this post, there is a problem with the benchmark code. It repeatedly inserts the same value. However, even after fixing this, the specialization problem is still happening.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you remove the explicit `forall` from `modifyWithM`. It looks like there were several bugs related to cross-module specialization that were fixed by some changes in 8.2.1 which you might try (if that's not what you are using): see related tickets on https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13376 . If you are using 8.2.1 I think you should report a bug

Comment: @jberryman Thanks for the suggestions. I went ahead and gave GHC 8.2 RC2 a try (I had been using RC1), and it did not fix the issue. I also tried getting rid of the `forall`, but that did not resolve it either.

Comment: Have you tried adding `INLINABLE` to the definition site? I think that's almost certainly necessary.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, it is marked as `INLINABLE` at the definition site.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Can you open a ticket on the issue tracker if it is?